# Problems with elasticsearch filtering

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm having trouble with filtering in elastic search.  I want to filter an index of order lines.  Like this sql query:

`SELECT * FROM orderrow WHERE item_code = '7X-BogusItem'`

Here's my elasticsearch query:

```
GET /myindex/orderrow/_search
{
    "query": {
        "constant_score": {
           "filter": {
               "term": {
                  "item_code": "7X-BogusItem"
               }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting no results back.  Yet when I run this query:

```
GET /myindex/orderrow/_search
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "7X-BogusItem"
        }
    }
}
```

I get the proper results.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The answer is describing the problem you have. If you want to keep the behavior of being able to search add a multi_field that you do not analyze. It is probably even better to use a filter instead of a query. You are not looking for scoring but looking for exact matches. When doing order lines you should also have a look at nested objects. This should give enough information to investigate further.

Answer (score 3):

You could try with:

```
GET /myindex/orderrow/_search
{
    "query": {
        "constant_score": {
           "filter": {
               "query": {
                  "query_string": {
                      "query": "7X-BogusItem"
                   }
               }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

The thing is that query_string query is analyzed while term query is not. Probably your data `7X-BogusItem` was transformed by default analyzer during indexing to terms like `7x` and `bogusitem`. When you try to do a query with term `7X-BogusItem` it will not work because you don't have term `7X-BogusItem` - you have only terms `7x` and `bogusitem`. However performing query_string will transform your query `7X-BogusItem` to terms `7x` and `bogusitem` under the hood and it will find what you want.

If you don't want your text `7X-BogusItem` to be transformed by analyzer, you could change mapping option for field `item_code` to `"index" : "not_analyzed"`.

You can check what your data will look like after analysis:

```
curl -XGET "localhost:9200/_analyze?analyzer=standard&pretty" -d '7X-BogusItem'
{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "7x",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 2,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "bogusitem",
    "start_offset" : 3,
    "end_offset" : 12,
    "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
    "position" : 2
  } ]
}
```

So for text `7X-BogusItem` we have in index terms `7x` and `bogusitem`.